# Microphone doesn't work

Tags: audio-recording

I'm having a trouble with my built in microphone. Even if I use headphone with mic, it doesn't really work. The weird thing is, if I clap the green lines of the speaker icon jumps, but if I speak it doesn't.

I have also tried some recordings, but I can not hear myself and adjusting the volume didn't help at all.

I tried to restore it, still no change.

I have updated it in the device manager, but it said there that it's up to date and the devices are working properly.

Until I decided to recover the whole system (wherein I pressed zero and switch on button) to my surprise, the settings became different, most programs were deleted, even my files. It's like it was formatted and I'm so sad that the mic was not fixed. I really don't know what to do now.

My laptop model is Toshiba satellite m840. I want to it return to its settings/set up just before I Recover the system and bring back all the programs that we're installed and of course, most of all, to fix my microphone so I can use Skype again and other video calling application.. I hope someone could help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which system? (BTW I would try to make your question more readable: one single dense paragraph is hard to read.

Comment: i tried to return it to its default factory settings because i thought it won't delete any program. But i was wrong. Most program were deleted.

Comment: so im wondering if i just restored it, or probably i made the wrong step. please help.. ;)

Comment: This sounds like a gating issue although unlikely. In what program are you monitoring the input level?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the mic sensitivity isn't high enough. Claps are louder than voices. Turning up mic boost should do the trick. The screenshot below should help (rightclick and view image/view image in new tab to see it full size)

[image]

Sadly a system restore is rather hard to fix, Restoring from a backup would be a good idea - overwritten data is almost impossible to recover.

Comment: yea, it worked this time! i can hear my voice now after recording, its not that loud, il try if it works in video call. :) thanks a lot!

Comment: my next step would be, installing those programs that were deleted. thanks! :)

Comment: it's working but it's too quiet. i have to shout.. :( what will i do? :(

Comment: turn up microphone as well? That should increase the volume. Other than that, if the mic isn't sensitive enough there's not much you can do, outside switching to a headset.